# Solving an augmented matrix already in row echelon form

Tags: matrices

I have the following augmented matrix that's in row echelon form that I need to solve:

\begin{bmatrix}4&3&7&2&4\\0&0&3&3&-6\end{bmatrix}

Where each number serves as a co-efficient to w, x, y, z respectively.
Getting this down in linear equation form you get:

4w + 3x + 7y + 2z = 4

3y + 3z = -6

I know with these types of questions you should let some of the unknowns be letters and I'm stuck with trying to figure out how to go about solving this matrix using such a method. I've tried to let w = t and x = s, but it doesn't seem to be acquiring the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed further and put the augmented matrix in *reduced* row echelon form:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
4&3&7&2&\color{red}4\\
0&0&3&3&\color{red}{-6}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
4&3&7&2&\color{red}4\\
0&0&1&1&\color{red}{-2}
\end{bmatrix}&\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
4&3&0&-5&\color{red}{18}\\
0&0&1&1&\color{red}{-2}
\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
&\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac43&1&0&-\frac53&\color{red}{6}\\
0&0&1&1&\color{red}{-2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The latter form means
\begin{cases}x=6-\frac43w+\frac53z,\\y=-2-z. \end{cases}

Answer (score 1):

Each equation in your system (each row in your matrix) is telling you how the variables relate to one another.  If you want to parametrize the set of solutions to the system, you can solve for some of the variables in each equation.

For example, you could rewrite the second equation as $3y = -6 - 3z$, or simply $y = \frac{-6 - 3z}{3} = -2 - z$.  This means that if you know what $z$ is, you know what $y$ has to be.  You could then plug that into your first equation to obtain $4w + 3x + 7(-2 - z) + 2z = 4$ which you could then rewrite as $4w + 3x - 5z = 19$.  Solving for $w$ would then tell you that $w = \frac{19 - 3x + 5z}{4}$.  (Double-check my arithmetic, btw.)

What you've done at this point is expressed the set of solutions to your system of equations in terms of two variables -- $x$ and $z$ in this case.  These are *free variables*: you can let $x$ and $z$ take on any value, and then you know what $w$ and $y$ must be with the equations above.

Notice in doing this we made a choice to solve for $y$ in the second equation, and then plugged that back into the first equation.  We could have instead solved for $z$ and plugged that back into the first equation, and likewise could have solved for $x$ instead of $w$ in the first equation.  So there are some choices we made along the way, and if you made those different choices you'd have a different parametrization (different way of representing all of the solutions) -- the set of solutions is still the same, but the way you're representing the solutions is different.

Comment: Cheers for that. I was wondering about what if I solved for z instead of y in the second equation, and if that would've been incorrect. It's just a matter of representing the solutions.